# Merge not contiguous partitions in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I am using a dual boot system with Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 8.1. So is it possible and how can I merge unallocated 123GiB which I freed in Windows from my D: Drive (/dev/sda2, ntfs) and move them to /dev/sda6 (84.75GiB, ext4)?

[image: Photo Link: GParted view of disks]

Comment: You can't do that. To merge non contiguous partitions you need to make your HDD a dynamic disk which Windows support but Linux don't

Comment: Don't merge them per se. Expand the extended partition, move up sda5, then expand sda6 into the new space.

Comment: You only have three primary partitions, so you could just make the unallocated another partition and mount it somewhere like /home, /usr/local/data,....

Comment: Re my comment, see https://askubuntu.com/q/126153/301745

Answer (score 0):

I did what [@ubfan1](https://askubuntu.com/users/82196) said in a [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115305/merge-not-contiguous-partitions-in-ubuntu-18-04#comment1841799_1115305):

> You only have three primary partitions, so you could just make the unallocated another partition and mount it somewhere like /home, /usr/local/data,....

So I did this in `/home/plus_data`. At the end of the day, the aim was to get more space.
Thanks